# Orange HRMS gives 'Internal Error Occurred'

Tags: php, orangehrm

I have upgraded PHP from version 5.6 to 7.0. In PHP 5.6 OrangeHRM is working fine. But, after the upgrading to version 7.0 it gives me **Internal Error Occurred**. I will appreciate is someone help me in this error.

Comment: Some spelling corrections

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's possible that oder Applications aren't compatible with PHP7. So in your code is something wrong and you get the status code 500. You have to enable all your error reporting and check your logs. Internal Server errors are hard to find because in most times can get not output.

I could find that OrangeHRM use the old `mysql` functions which are removed in PHP7. So you can't use PHP7 in that case.

[Orange HRM is not Working for PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423706/orange-hrm-is-not-working-for-php-7)

So check the change log a gain for the last version if it's compatible. If it's not then go back to PHP 5.6 or you have to change to another software.

Answer (score 0):

OrangeHRM open source is not compatible with PHP7 yet. Only enterprise product (after version 6.4) is compatible with PHP7. If you want to move with PHP7 you have to go with OrangeHRM 6.4 or higher. (Checked and Verified with an OrangeHRM developer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the **Internal Error Occurred** in Red, You can check the **status of mysql service**, get to be root user, check the mysql status if inactive, **start mysql services**.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is this.
Goto your Wamp>MySQL>MySQL Settings>SQL-Mode-> then select SQL-Mode None

Thank you